# Eclipse JSF + facelet - opening and editing page is slow

Tags: eclipse, jsf, facelets, trinidad

When opening JSF page (JSF + Apache Trinidad + facelet) in Eclipse (Helios), Eclipse freezes for a few seconds before the page is opened.

Also when editing the page, code complete / syntax verification is slow - for example I type `<tr`: and again I have to wait a few seconds before I can continue typing or tr tags are display.

It is very annoying that I have to wait each time when typing opening tag and slows me down a lot.

I am also using custom facelet tags.

What to do to avoid Eclipse freezing / slowing down? Do I have to change any configuration to speed it up?

Comment: I'm getting the same with Eclipse/JSF2.0/EJB3.0

Answer (score 5):

I tried using the XHTML Editor instead of the JSF editor, and the freezing seems to have stopped.

I right clicked on my *.xhtml file and selected Open with->XHTML Designer

Also, you could change the way *.xhtml files are opened by going to Window->Preferences, then General->Editors->File Associations. Select the *.xhtml extension from the File types: pane, and then select XHTML Designer in the Associated editors: pane. To make the XHTML Editor the default editor for *.xhtml files, click the "Default" button next to the Associated editors: pane.

Comment: I didn't found this option in RAD, do I need to install XHTML Designer from external source or it has to be built in?

Comment: @Anatoly are you succeeded in solving this issue?

Comment: Found the blog post with this solution: it's *XML* editor : http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2008/03/facelets-and-xsd-converted-tlds.html

Comment: @Anton, I used exactly what **bakoyaro** explained, and it worked well

Answer (score 2):

Turn off hyperlinks in your editor by going to the following path

`Go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Hyperlinking preference`,

***uncheck*** the option Open Declaration

Comment: I only unchecked the option "Facelet EL Hyperlink Detector" (also in the same place that indicates @Ozan Emrah Yakupoğlu) and worked perfect!

Comment: I have unchecked Facelet EL Hyperlink Detector AND JSP EL Hyperlink Detector

Comment: perfectly working

Answer (score 1):

I had this problems for weeks, and I've found a solution:

- Install JBoss Tools > JBoss Web and Java EE Development > Visual Page
  Editor (only this subpackage)

After you can edit XHTML files with:

- Open with > JBoss Tools HTML Editor

It's faster and gives you a better page preview

Answer (score 1):

Some profiling show that the slowness is due to

`org/eclipse/jst/jsf/context/symbol/internal/impl/IJavaTypeDescriptor2Impl.class`

[image]

Its related to org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common_1.2.2.v201101211220.jar of WebTool 1.2.2

The solution is to update to the last WebTool version
[WebTool 3.6.2 update page](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)

using [Update Webtool Luna link](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/luna/)

Adding `metadata-complete=true` to WEB-INF/faces-config.xml is a good way to prevent WebTool packages classes scanning, but AnnotationConfigurator.createFacesConfig must be modified !

Answer (score -1):

For eclipse

> Windows -> Preferences -> Editor -> File associations

then select XHtml.

After the selection there will be three options in the bottom window select HTML editor and click default. This solved the problem for me.

Please make sure to close all the opened XHtml pages and restart the eclipse.